# Let Apache reply TLS error OR close connection if SNI not match any enabled name-based virtualhost

Tags: apache, ssl, https, tls1.2, sni

##What I want:
I'm looking for a way to let Apache either send a handshake_failure error or close the connection if the client has the wrong SNI within the Client Hello message.

### Break this problem into parts, and the research I've done:

1. Apache is able to get the SNI value from the client

Solved: Apache - mod_ssl has "SSL_TLS_SNI" in its Environment Variables.

2. Apache can check if the SNI is included in the current list of name-based vhosts.

Not Solved: But this is not that important, I can use SetEnvIf and match manually.

3. This is the hardest part for me: **Let Apache close the connection or reply a  TLS error** ([RFC 5246 - 7.2.2.  Error Alerts](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2.2)) to client. I can not find any way to do that.

### Other Questions you may ask

- What if client doesn't support SNI?

  I enabled the SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck, therefore, Clients will get a handshake_failure error if SNI was not sent.
- Why you prefer close the connection / reply TLS error instead of just show the error?

I don't want my server send the cert info before the client know the correct domain. (I know there are other ways to get around this) And I am just trying to challenge myself finding a way to intercept a connection on TCP/TLS layer on Apache. This is the precondition, no need to discuss.

###Please give me some hints or share your similar experience with me.

Thanks.